# dust.js eq helper is not working

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js

I have the following json:

```
{ "list": [ 
    { "course": "math",    "type": "1" }, 
    { "course": "science", "type": "1" }, 
    { "course": "gym",     "type": "2" }, 
    { "course": "art",     "type": "3" }
 ]
}
```

here is my template:

```
{#list}
  {@eq key=type value="1"}
     {course} {type}
  {/eq}
   {:else}
    no course,
{/list}
```

the {:else} is not working.  it prints:  no course, no course, no course, no course,  (the amount of times that prints it is the number of records in the array

I want to show all courses with type=1 and print "no course" if no type=1 is found

anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are very close. The correct syntax is:

```
{@eq key=type value="1"}
   {course} {type}
{:else}
    No course
{/eq}
```

Your mistake is that you have closed the `@eq` helper before opening the `else`, but the `else` is actually part of the `@eq` helper. The same applies for `?`, `#`, and any other place that `:else` is used.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  i don't think i explained it enough.  What I am trying to do is filter the json by the key value and show only those results.  if there are no records with the key value (ie: if i enter value=5 it should show the "no course".  I tried your solution  with key value=1 and it gave me this result: math1,science1,No course,No course.  What i am looking for is: key value=1: math1,science1  or key value=7 no course.  I don't know if i need an @if helper.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you've by now solved this, but a good solution may be to write your own helper:

```
dust.helpers.course_filter = function(chunk, context, bodies, params){
  if(params.key == 1){
    bodies.block(chunk, context);
  } else {
    bodies.else(chunk, context);
  }
};
```

Then in your template:

```
{#list}
 {@course_filter key=type}
  {course} {type}
 {:else}
  No course
 {/course_filter}
{/list}
```

**EDIT:**
After reading your response to the other answer, I believe my example will give the same result which you weren't hoping for.  I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're trying to get but a custom helper generally provides much more flexibility in terms of getting there